# adding dynamic data to MPAndroidChart

Tags: mpandroidchart

Can anyone explain with a simple example on how to add the data dynamically to the chart which is already drawn. I tried with the details in the github link to add the data, but couldn't do so. A very short example or link is also fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the project here https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/archive/master.zip
Open the project, and in **MPChartExample**, you have the file **DynamicalAddingActivity.java**.

1. You need to create the chart:
2. Add dataSet (your line(s)) with the values (please view the example in
   **addDataSet()** method in **MPChartExample** project).
3. After you can do a CountTimerDown that add a new Entry, for the
   dataset.

> ```
> /** each 5 seconds **/
> new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
>
>      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
>      }
>
>      public void onFinish() {
>         double randomValue = 19.0 + (Math.random() * (21.0 - 19.0)); 
>         int indexOfMyLine = 0;
>
>         Entry newEntry = new Entry((float) randomValue, indexOfMyLine); 
>      }
> ```
>
> }.start();